# moving subfolder A from svn to git--but A used to be named B in SVN

Tags: git, svn

I want to migrate an svn subfolder to git.

```
trunk/A
```

A ways back in `A`'s svn history it was called `B`.  It was renamed with `svn move`.

Is it possible to use `git svn clone` but preserve the history that happened when `A` was called `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the subdirectory in the `git svn clone` command:

```
git svn clone -T trunk/A <url>
```

The history before `svn move` will be preserved. And you will see something like this in the git log (output from my little testing repo.):

```
git-svn-id: file:///tmp/repo/trunk/A@4 d2e77d6f-2e9c-4e30-b277-8892017077a6

git-svn-id: file:///tmp/repo/trunk/A@3 d2e77d6f-2e9c-4e30-b277-8892017077a6

git-svn-id: file:///tmp/repo/trunk/B@1 d2e77d6f-2e9c-4e30-b277-8892017077a6
```

Or you may try the following command to migrate the whole svn repository. This will maintain all the branch, tag information in svn repositories in git.

```
git svn clone -s -r 40000:HEAD <url>
```

- `-s` for `--stdlayout`, the trunk, branch, tag convention used by svn
- `-r` for the revision to start taking history from. If `-r` is not specified, clone all the revisions.

Comment: Hopefully the problem wasn't a bad `svn move` in the first place then.

Comment: Is it important to specify `-T`?  I omitted this because I wasn't checkout out `trunk`, I was checking out `trunk/A`.